# How to allow HTML/Javascript intellisense in self-developed .Net Server Control inner text?

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls, servercontrols, servercontrol

We've developed our custom .Net Server Control for our ASP.Net project use. It allows users to put HTML/Javascript code into its inner text node. The problem is, when the user is inputting the HTML/Javascript inside the server control, they can't benefit from the built-in intellisense of the Visual Studio. How can we change the implementation of the server in order provide that?

Thanks.

--- EDITED ---
For example:
The tag for the self-developed server control is , I mean the intellisense for the inner html/javascript in it, for example

```
<MyServerContol>
    var str1 = 'hello world';
    console.log('Msg is ' + str1);
</MyServerControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the public properties of the control with `Browsable(true)` attribute. That way visual studio will show it in intellisense.

you have to import / using `System.ComponentModel` where browsable attribute class is.

Comment: Thanks, your answer means to wrap the server control as part of the intellisense in the application scope; but I'm asking the provide intellisense in the inner text of our server control.

Comment: Hi, in general cases, asp.net user controls are not built like this, if you want to support templating in user controls, you have to do something like - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/06/04/Supporting-Templates-with-ASP.NET-User-Controls.aspx
let me know if you need more help